# embedding movies using media9 does not work. compiles without errors

Tags: embedding, media9, multimedia

Embedding movies using `media9` does not work. Linking to online movies does. I am sure that I am using the correct mp4 format and h264 encoding so the problem should not be with the movie files.

The document compiles without errors, however when I open the document there is either a blank space or a grey rectangle. How can this problem be solved? Have others experienced similar problems? I can view the movies and 3d content in the `\media9` package documentation.

```
\documentclass[12pt,landscape]{article}

\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
the beginning of the document

\includemedia[
activate=pageopen,
height=170pt,
addresource=video.mp4,
flashvars={%
source=video.mp4
&scaleMode=stretch}
]{}{VPlayer.swf}

the end of the document
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The video area in your example has zero width. You only specify the height through the `height`option. The poster argument is empty from which the width could be taken.

TeX cannot determine video dimensions from the video file. They must be provided either via options `width` ***and*** `height` or by using a poster image/text. In the latter case, the video can be resized using any or a combination of `width`, `height`, `depth`, `scale`.

Comment: I have implemented your advice but my problem is not solved. I am greeted with a blank rectangle with a clickable error message "unable to play 'video.mp4'". Clicking on it dismisses the error message and leaves a blank rectangle. My video is made from jpeg images. I convert jpeg images to an avi movie in VirtualDub, then use 'Simple Video Converter' to convert .avi into .mp4 (H264). Are there video format requirements beyond the encoding and format that I am not aware of?

Comment: additionally, if I use StrobeMediaPlayback.swf instead of VPlayer.swf then I get the error messages 'We are unable to connect to the content you've requested. We apologize for the inconvenience.' and when i click on it again, 'TypeError - Error #1009'.

Comment: Please check whether the file `random.mp4` from the `media9` package works with your code (using `VPlayer.swf`). If so, your video file hasn't been correctly encoded. I recommend `ffmpeg` for producing h264 from jpegs or existing video files (avi, mpeg, ...). See the media9 doc (Introduction) for instructions.

Comment: Your solution is helpful, random.mp4 plays as expected. However when I play a 10mb movie that is converted from .avi to .mp4 using the ffmpeg command in the media9 doc, it does not work, and only the grey rectangle appears. What could be causing the different result?

Comment: Perhaps the `libx264` codec is not compiled into your installed `ffmpeg` version. Try an online service where you can upload an existing video file, such as http://video.online-convert.com/convert-to-mp4.

Comment: i have some working examples now. This problem is solved :)